# Dynamic box2d object color does not cange

Tags: javascript, box2d

In box2D I am using this js function to create a green box:

```
createBox(world, 8.50, 3.80, 1 , 1, {type : b2Body.b2_dynamicBody, 'user_data' : {'fill_color' : 'rgba(204,237,165,1)' , 'border_color' : '#7FE57F' }});
```

And the function is here:

```
function createBox(world, x, y, width, height, options) 
{

     //default setting
    options = $.extend(true, {
        'density' : 2.5 ,
        'friction' : 2.0 ,
        'restitution' : 2.5 ,

        'type' : b2Body.b2_dynamicBody
    }, options);

    var body_def = new b2BodyDef();
    var fix_def = new b2FixtureDef();

    fix_def.density = options.density;
    fix_def.friction = options.friction;
    fix_def.restitution = options.restitution;

    fix_def.shape = new b2PolygonShape();

    fix_def.shape.SetAsBox( width/2 , height/2 );

    body_def.position.Set(x , y);

    body_def.type = options.type;

    body_def.userData =options.user_data;

    var b = world.CreateBody( body_def );
    var f = b.CreateFixture(fix_def);

    return b;
}
```

When I try to make `static` object it becomes green, but **for `dynammic` object it does not**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not grasp the question correctly. Does the dynamic object show at all ? or is it just a different colour ( usually brown ) ?

Comment: It shows but the problem is with color!

Comment: What is the problem then. Can you put a image up. You do not exactly explain the problem. "When I try to make static object it becomes green, but for dynamic object it does not." this sentence is ambiguous to me. The problem is that its not green ?